# I try to read a binary file and want to display it in a format like a dump

Tags: python, binary, hex, decode, dump

From python program binary read I get the following data:

```
hex_string = '0004576965646572766f726c61676500'
print(bytes.fromhex(hex_string))
    result --> b'\x00\x04Wiedervorlage\x00'

print(bytes.fromhex(hex_string).hex(' ', 4))
    result --> 00045769 65646572 766f726c 61676500

print(bytes.fromhex(hex_string).decode("ASCII"))
    result --> ♦Wiedervorlage
```

but what I want to get is something like this:

```
00045769 65646572 766f726c 61676500
....W.i. e.d.e.r. v.o.r.l. a.g.e...
```

I tried to find a function for that but could not find anyone.

For a helpful hint many thanks in advance.
Paul

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147225/python-hex-viewer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard function to do exactly what you want, and you did not ask a question.

Here is a way to implement it, a bit ugly though :

```py
hex_string = "0004576965646572766f726c61676500"

printable_range = range(0x20, 0x7F)
chunks = [hex_string[i : i + 8] for i in range(0, len(hex_string), 8)]  # 4 bytes each = 8 hex digits
res = ""
for chunk in chunks:
    for byte in bytes.fromhex(chunk):
        if byte in printable_range:
            res += chr(byte) + "."
        else:
            res += ".."
    res += " "

print(bytes.fromhex(hex_string).hex(" ", 4))
print(res)
```

outputs

```
00045769 65646572 766f726c 61676500
....W.i. e.d.e.r. v.o.r.l. a.g.e...
```